# VAADIN (Server response didn't contain an id)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to navigate through views in my application and I suddenly get this in the console of debugger like:
com.vaadin.client.VConsole SEVERE: Server response didn't contain an id

And I getting this error message at the top of my page.
Communication problem Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC to continue. 
I am using VAADIN 7.2.0 And I was on 7.1.13 before with the same error. Please I need anyone's suggestion to solve this issue it's really annoying.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a window/page open twice somewhere? Usually this happens when you open the same window twice...

Comment: Just a heads up; this exact issue is being discussed on the [Vaadin forums](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/7699248) as well.